# 2013 consumer rights apllicability

Tags: consumer-protection

I live in Germany. If I buy something from England and it does not, or cannot work in Germany do I have protection with the 2015 consumer rights law?

Comment: I’m confused as to how it can work in England but not in Germany.

Comment: Power plugs are different, but usually easily exchanged. 30 years ago TVs worked in one country but not another. Phones can still be limited to some countries, but most work in many countries.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the seller promised that the product would work in Germany and it didn't, a product sold in the UK would be consider to be fine if it is working fine in the UK.